# Flutter: Generics assignment is not working on extended types of T

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

Why this generic classes throw errors? Since `T extends DataModel`, it should allow to assign instances of `DataModel` but isn't.

```dart
class TestClass<T extends DataModel> {
  List<T> variablesList = [];
  late T variable;

  void run() {
    variablesList.add(DataModel(id: '', name: '', value: '')); // error
    variable = DataModel(id: '', name: '', value: ''); // error
  }

  void run2() {
    variablesList.add(DateModelImpl(id: '', name: '', value: '')); // error
    variable = DateModelImpl(id: '', name: '', value: ''); // error
  }
}

class DataModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String value;

  DataModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.value,
  });
}

class DateModelImpl extends DataModel {
  DateModelImpl({
    required String id,
    required String name,
    required String value,
  }) : super(id: id, name: name, value: value);
}
```

Error:

> The argument type 'DataModel' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.

> The argument type 'DateModelImpl' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since T extends DataModel, it should allow to assign instances of DataModel but isn't.

No, it should not. It's pretty simple: A `Pack<Wolf>` is something like `Pack<T extends Animal>`, but that does not mean you can just add *any* animal to a pack of wolves, nor can you add any derived class of Animal that is *not* `wolf` (lets say `Sheep`) to a `Pack<Wolf>`. Only another `Wolf` can be added. If you want to be able to add any animal, maybe generics is not the way to go and you should rather use interfaces or base classes.